# Mapreduce queue Setup

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a jar called `WordCountMain.jar`. I would like to run this jar using hadoop command in multimode cluster.

but my user id is tagged to queue name as "omega". so if I run the above jar using the below command then I am getting a error that indicates that my id is not having submit_job access.

```
hadoop jar WordCountMain.jar /user/cloudera/inputs/words.txt /user/cloudera/output
```

So the above command not works in multimode cluster,but it works in single node CDH3 cluster

*How do i include the queue name while running the above jar?*

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

Job job = new Job(conf,"word count");
job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename","omega");

job.setJarByClass(WordCountCombinerMain.class);

Path inputFilePath = new Path(args[0]);
Path outputFilePath = new Path(args[1]);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputFilePath);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputFilePath);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

job.setMapperClass(CWordCountMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(CWordCountCombiner1.class);
job.setReducerClass(CWordCountCombiner1.class);
//job.setReducerClass(CwordCountReducer.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.waitForCompletion(true);
job.submit();
```

But i am getting  the below error. This error says that my mapreduce job is  get submitted on default queue.. Can someone help me on this

```
ERROR ipc.RPC: FailoverProxy: Failing this Call: submitJob for error(RemoteException):       org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User mytra cannot perform operation SUBMIT_JOB on queue default
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the possible solutions in your driver class

- Solution1: `configuration.set("mapred.job.queue.name", "omega");`
- Solution2:

  ```
  String queueName= "omega";
  job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename", queueName);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`-Dmapred.job.queue.name=yourpoolname` or `-Dmapreduce.job.queuename=yourpoolname`
as a parameter to submit Jobs to different queues.

Be aware that `mapred.job.queue.name` is a deprecated property name and new name is `mapreduce.job.queuename` after Hadoop 2.4.1.